# How to add two digits / two letters to a string in a column (if some condition it is met)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a year column which it is composed by 2 or 4 digits.

Thefore, in order to have a column in the same structure I would like to add '19' to my year colum.

My data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"year" : ["1993", "85", "1971", "75", "56"]} 
data  = pd.Series(data)
```

and it should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"year" : ["1993", "1985", "1971", "1975", "1956"]} 
data  = pd.Series(data)
```

I was trying something like:

```
for col in data:
    if data.str.len()==2:
        data= '19' + data
```

however there was no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use if all **data are always less like `2000`** is possible add `19` for rows with length `2`:

```
data = {"year" : ["1993", "85", "1971", "75", "56"]} 
data  = pd.DataFrame(data)

data.loc[data['year'].str.len()==2, 'year'] = '19' + data['year']
print (data)
   year
0  1993
1  1985
2  1971
3  1975
4  1956
```

Or @yatu super solution - always add `19` to all last 2 values:

```
data['year'] = '19'+data.year.str[-2:]
```

---

**If possible last years, it means `2000+`**, so sometimes should be add `20` or `19` one idea is distinguish it by compare if year is greater like `20` and pass to [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
data = {"year" : ["1993", "85", "1971", "75", "56", '20']} 
data  = pd.DataFrame(data)

m1 = data['year'].str.len()==2 
m2 = data['year'].astype(int) > 20

data['year'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], ['19', '20'], '') + data['year']
print (data)
   year
0  1993
1  1985
2  1971
3  1975
4  1956
5  2020
```

Comment: @yatu - hmmm, it is more complicated, because 2000

Comment: I think slicing the last 2 chars and always adding `19` is dangerous. If OP has some 2000+ years such as `2010`, `2015`, they will be turned to `1910`, `1915`